# What kind of SSD is this? (found in my Asus EEE 900)

Tags: ssd, eee-pc

Thinking the SSD in my EEE 900 was about to collapse, I opened it up to find out what kind of SSD I would need to buy to replace the old one.

It looks like they have some small card, and since I have not seen this type before I wonder if this is some kind of standard?

[image: image of SSD]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find exactly what SSD that is, but it's a variant of a standard called Mini PCI-E or PCI Express Mini. As detailed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#EeePC_flash_connector), you need the specific type used by the Eee, of which [this](http://www.mydigitaldiscount.com/SPD/runcore-32gb-pro-sata-70mm-mini-pci-e-pcie-ssd-for-asus-eee-pc-900-and-s101---in-stock-runcore-32gb-pro-70mm-sata-mini-pcie-solid-state-drive-ssd-for-asus-eee-pc-900-s101--8000092A-1231822185.jsp) is a good example. A guide to upgrading to it can be found [here](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2009/02/upgrading_the_ssd_in_an_eee_pc_900.html).